# How to provide credentials for s3 bucket provider to Velero when creating a new backup-location

Tags: kubernetes, velero

Velero is installed in the cluster. At the installation velero was given credentials to s3 provider with `--secret-file` parameter and everything works fine.

Now I would like to create a new backup-location which will use buckets from a different s3 provider. When creating a backup location I pass to `--config` a key/value pair of `s3Url=...` But I can't seem to find a way to add a way to pass credentials to the new a3 provider. The `--secret-file` flag that worked at install is not accepted.

As the result when calling `backup create` with the new `--storage-location` the backup is created as failed.

My question is how I can give velero a way to authenticate itself with the new s3 provider? Is it even possible to create a new backup-location using s3 provider different that that used at velero install?

Comment: What are the current and new s3 providers?

Comment: @Nick current - AWS, new - in house S3 compatible storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://velero.io/docs/v1.2.0/locations/) says:

> Velero only supports a single set of credentials per provider. It's
>   not yet possible to use different credentials for different locations,
>   if they're for the same provider.

So I am afraid it is not possible at the moment to add new credentials.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from [Velero Issue Tracker](https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero/labels/P2%20-%20Long-term%20important?page=2&q=is%3Aopen+label%3A%22P2+-+Long-term+important%22), they are working on fixing **[that issue](https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero/issues/1064)**, however it still hasn't been properly implemented.